# Step to configure ML Kit library model in podfile - flutter apps

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, face-detection

I am new in using ios, and right now I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision to do face detection... here is said that
`If you're using one of the on-device APIs, include the corresponding ML Kit library model in your Podfile. Then run pod update in a terminal within the same directory as your Podfile.` and right now I am using 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel' and I need to do `pod 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel'`... since I am new in using ios, I am trying to find a tutorial how to configure it in ios, but I still don't find yet... what I don't understand here is how to include the corresponding ML Kit library model in my Podfile... should I edit it inside Xcode or inside ios folder in my flutter project?... is anyone here know how step by step to configure it?
and here is what I get when I didn't set that up

```
Xcode build done.                                           26.9s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x00000001064aafca +[FIRApp configure] + 138
    4   Runner                              0x0000000106a6dab6 -[FLTFirebaseMlVisionPlugin init] + 214
    5   Runner                              0x0000000106a6d8f3 +[FLTFirebaseMlVisionPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 211
    6   Runner                              0x00000001064a5bf5 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 309
    7   Runner                    <…>
```